# Three different methods in Laravel for if the request is asking for JSON. Are they the same? Do any overlap?

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller

So these three methods are in the Laravel docs for testing if the request is for JSON.

I basically want to return JSON for any request that is requesting JSON or AJAX.

`Request::ajax()
 Request::isJson()
 Request::wantsJson()`

Can I use any of these?  Do they overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For 2023 visitors:**

**TL;DR**

- **`ajax()`** only checks the method of a `request` call, not the formatting. The `request` and the `response` can be of any type.
- **`isJson()`** only checks the formatting of the `request`. The `request` must be in JSON format, but the `response` can be of any type.
- **`wantsJson()`** only checks the formatting of the `response`. The `response` must be in JSON format, but the `request` can be of any type.
- For **`expectsJson()`**, please read the full text. This method has a story that makes [Mustafa Akçakaya's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086396/mustafa-ak%C3%A7akaya) answer and [MR_AMDEV's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10114772/mr-amdev) answer incomplete or incorrect.

**The **Laravel 10** documentation and method definitions can be  confusing, especially when using functions like `wantsJson()`.**

**It's essential to be cautious when using these functions, as the output may be `True` in Postman but `False` in the browser.**

**`ajax()`**[1](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax):

1. Determines if the `request` is a result of an AJAX call.
2. It only concerns the `request`.
3. The `request` must be of type `XMLHttpRequest`, indicating an AJAX call.
4. This is an AJAX request if a JavaScript library like [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) or [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) sets an `X-Requested-With` HTTP header.
5. Only this header is necessary, so you can manually add or merge that header to your `request`.
6. The method is not related to the format or `response`.

**`isJson()`**[2](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_isJson):

1. Determine if the `request` is sending JSON.
2. It's all about formatting the `request`.
3. To ensure correct formatting, it looks for `/json` **OR** `+json` in the **content-type header**.

**`wantsJson()`**[3](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.html#method_wantsJson):

1. Determine if the current `request` is requesting JSON as the `response`.
2. It's all about the `response`.
3. In the `response` *, it must be set* as an **`accept`** header.
4. If the `accept` header is preset and filled (is set) ***and*** [contains `/json` **OR** `+json`], it returns true.

**`expectsJson()`**[4](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.html#method_expectsJson):

1. Determine if the current request expects a JSON response.
2. It returns true in two different conditions.

- Checks if the `request` is ajax **AND** not pjax **AND** accepts any content type. So, in this condition, the `response` may be anything.
- Or `wantsJson()`.

3. It may be about the `request`.
4. It may be about the `response`.
5. In the `response`, *it may be set* as an `accept` header.
6. If the `accept` header is set, it may contain any content type.

**Please let me know if you have any questions.**

Answer (score 14):

Not all AJAX requests expect a JSON response, so utilizing `request()->ajax()` is useful where you want to determine if the request was an `XmlHttpRequest` or not, but the response doesn't care about JSON or not.

Not all requests that contain JSON expect a JSON response. so if you don't care about whether or not the response wants JSON back, but want to determine if JSON was sent in the request, then `isJson()` is useful for you.

Not all requests that want JSON responses are AJAX driven, so `wantsJson` is useful in the case where you want to return `JSON` data, but you don't care how the request came to your server.

Based on these descriptions, make assertions and choose the proper functions.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. That's what I was wondering. So each of these has their own use case and exists for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Request::expectsJson()`. It returns true if request is ajax or wants json.

Answer (score 1):

1. `request()->ajax()` is usefull if you want to check if request is only **Ajax**
2. `Request::wantsJson()` is usefull if you want to check if request is only **Json**
3. `Request::expectsJson()` is usefull if you want to check if request is either **Ajax or Wants Json**